# trying to use [pffacebookUtils logininbackgrounwithreadpermission], but get error about fbinternalutility validatescheme

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk, pffacebookutils

I'm using

```
[PFFacebookUtils loginInbackgroundWithReadPermission ...
```

to log in my user.

However, I received this error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FBSDKInternalUtility validateURLSchemes]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10b695e40'

I have looked through all the header files; but I just cannot find a class named as FBSDKInternalUtility. Before the upgrade of Parse 1.7.2 and Facebook SDK v4, my log in system works perfectly.

Please help.

Comment: `PFFacebookUtils loginInBackgroundWithReadPermission` work correctly for me even after migrating to FB SDK v4. Do you import all of these: `<Parse/Parse.h>`, `<ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>` and `<FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>` in the .m where you call this method?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out, OP?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't added `FBSDKCoreKit.framework` to your project. Add the framework and make sure that you add `#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>` to your file.